# Intellij Idea утечка памяти IDE

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, ide, память, memory

Проблема в следующем:

1. Открываю проект в Intellij Idea, жду когда IDE и проект обновит все свои индексы и закончит открываться;
2. В System Monitor (Ubuntu) смотрю сколько потребляет памяти процесс Intellij Idea;
3. Возвращаюсь в открытый проект (ничего не нажимаю), и снова перехожу обратно к просмотру потребляемой памяти System Monitor и вижу как к потребляемой памяти добавляется по 2-3 мегабайта;
4. При повторении пункта 3, процесс потребляет все больше и больше памяти на 2-3 мегабайта за кажую смену фокуса. Т.е. сам факт смены фокуса на проект, добавляет к потребляемой памяти 2-3 мегабайта. Если по-переходить по открытым файлам, то потреблять будет еще больше. Повторный просмотр открытых файлов также добавляет потребляемой памяти.

Вопрос: что это? и с чем может быть связано?

Сторонних плагинов не установлено.

**Intellij Idea**

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.6
Build #IU-163.15188.11, built on March 25, 2017

JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

**ОС**

Ubuntu: 16.04 LTS

Memory: 7,6 GiB

OS type: 64-bit

Disk: 253.7 Gib

Comment: Ну она же на джаве - зачем ей освобождать память сразу... И вообще, полазь в настройках, там где-то был лимит потребления памяти и лимит использования памяти под кэш, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Qwertiy а это нормально, что память заполняется при смене фокуса? Проект же не запущен, объекты не создаются, куда уходит память?

Comment: Понятия не имею. Но я бы сначала заглянул в настройки, а там бы уже спрашивал, если начнутся конкретные проблемы.